# How do I add values to a dictionary where the keys are already input by the user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This would be the exercise im currently working on: Write a function ***distinct_characters*** that gets a list of strings as a parameter. It should return a dictionary whose keys are the strings of the input list and the corresponding values are the numbers of distinct characters in the key.

**Solution: { "check" : 4, "look" : 3, "try" : 3, "pop" : 2}**

My code:

```
    def distinct_characters(l):
            dictOfWords = {i: 5 for i in l}
            for key in dictOfWords:
            keys = (len(set(key[0:len(dictOfWords)])))
         print(dictOfWords)

    distinct_characters(["check", "look", "try", "pop", "obo", "hehe"])
```

***Output: {'check': 5, 'look': 5, 'try': 5, 'pop': 5, 'obo': 5, 'hehe': 5}***

I have tried the for loop without using key but iam not returning the usual format of a dictionary

```
    def distinct_characters(l):
         dictOfWords = {i: 5 for i in l}
         for i in dictOfWords:
            print(len(set(i[0:len(dictOfWords)])), i, end=" ")

distinct_characters(["check", "look", "try", "pop", "obo", "hehe"])
```

> ***Output: 4 check 3 look 3 try 2 pop 2 obo 2 hehe***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note--you never modify your original `dictOfWords` after you create it. Also, when you create the dictionary, you assign a value of `5` to each word that serves as a key.

You can accomplish this in a pythonic way using dict comprehensions like so:

```
def disctinct_characters(listofwords):
    return {word: len(set(word)) for word in listofwords}
```

Comment: also, to answer the question that you posed in the title--if you ever want to update the value stored under an already-existing key in a dictionary, you can just access the value using normal dictionary access. In your original code snippet, you could update the value stored under each key like this: `dictOfWords[key] = len(set(key))`.

Comment: Also, I'd watch your indentation in the original code snippet you posted--the statement that you've posted right underneath your for loop does not run in your for loop.

Comment: Your comment helped me realize that I completely overlooked the line where i assigned the value 5. Thanks alot! I figured out the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def distinct_characters(l):
    d=dict()
    for i in l:
        k = set(i)
        d[i] = len(k)
    return d
distinct_characters(["check", "look", "try", "pop", "obo", "hehe"])
```

This would do the work !

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should work.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def distinct_characters(l):
    result = {}
    for each in l:
        temp = defaultdict(int)
        for char in each:
            temp[char] += 1
        result[each] = len(temp)

    return result

print(distinct_characters(["check", "look", "try", "pop", "obo", "hehe"]))
```

I have used defaultdict to avoid the keyerror. Basically, it's same as the default python dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your help!